# Bootstrap 4 text-center in flexbox not working

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to split my webpage into two vertical columns which can be clicked on to take you to the right pages. I've gotten this far.

HTML

```
<!-- Choices -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 vertical-center webd">
            <h1 class="text-muted text-center">Web Design</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 vertical-center circ">
            <h1 class="text-muted text-center">Circus</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.vertical-center {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.webd {
    background-image: url('webd.jpg');
}

.circ {
    background-image: url(circ.JPG);
}
```

My issue is, no matter where I put the `text-center` class. My `<h1>`s stay left aligned on the page. Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you want to align the h1 itself, or only the text content in it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because you have added display flex to the parent container.  This means the children are not full width anymore.

If you add the following style, it will fix your error:

```
.vertical-center > .text-center 
{
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[Example bootply](http://www.bootply.com/9I4Oer6QEi)

If you don't want to grow the children, you can just add the following to your vertical center: `justify-content: center;`

[Example bootply 2](http://www.bootply.com/UaFaFtYbPs)